# How do scan an open book with openCV and Python?

Tags: python, opencv

[1.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnVAd.jpg) [2.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azh7k.jpg) [3.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/641Oe.jpg) [4.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/il21T.jpg) [5.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNUwi.jpg) [save_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKW8N.jpg)

We are working on a project on how to recognize books in the library. When I take pictures of books in various cases, I find the largest outline of the book, I take four vertices, and I code them to recognize only the book through plane conversion with those four vertices. what is the best way to recognize a book? I upload 5 example pictures, successful pictures, and the code I made. Thank you. The successful picture is 5.jpg.
It was proceeded in eight order.

1. grayscale
2. threshold+otsu
3. canny
4. gaussianblur
5. dilate and erode
6. find contours
7. largest contours
8. warpPerspective

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


#initializing
img = cv2.imread("5.jpg")
img = cv2.resize(img, (int(480*2), int(640*2)))
"""
# shadow remove
rgb_planes = cv2.split(img)
result_planes = []
result_norm_planes = []
for plane in rgb_planes:
    dilated_img = cv2.dilate(plane, np.ones((7,7), np.uint8))
    bg_img = cv2.medianBlur(dilated_img, 21)
    diff_img = 255 - cv2.absdiff(plane, bg_img)
    norm_img = cv2.normalize(diff_img,None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8UC1)
    result_planes.append(diff_img)
    result_norm_planes.append(norm_img)
remove_shadow_img = cv2.merge(result_planes)
remove_shadow_img_norm = cv2.merge(result_norm_planes)
"""




# write code here
GrayImg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)



high_thresh, thresh_im = cv2.threshold(GrayImg, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
lowThresh = 0.5*high_thresh

CannyFrame=cv2.Canny(thresh_im,lowThresh,high_thresh)
GaussianImg=cv2.GaussianBlur(CannyFrame,(5,5),1)
kernel = np.ones((5, 5))
imgDial = cv2.dilate(GaussianImg, kernel, iterations=2) # APPLY DILATION
imgThreshold = cv2.erode(imgDial, kernel, iterations=1)  # APPLY EROSION





contours, _ = cv2.findContours(imgThreshold, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

CornerFrame = img.copy()
maxArea = 0
biggest = []

for i in contours:
    area=cv2.contourArea(i)
    if area > 1000 :
        peri = cv2.arcLength(i, True)
        edges = cv2.approxPolyDP(i, 0.02*peri, True)
        if area > maxArea and len(edges) == 4 :
            biggest = edges
            maxArea = area
            biggest_fake=np.squeeze(biggest,axis=1)
            sm=biggest_fake.sum(axis=1)
            diff=np.diff(biggest_fake,axis=1)


            topLeft = biggest_fake[np.argmin(sm)]  # x+y가 가장 작은 값이 좌상단 좌표
            bottomRight = biggest_fake[np.argmax(sm)]  # x+y가 가장 큰 값이 우하단 좌표
            topRight = biggest_fake[np.argmin(diff)]  # x-y가 가장 작은 것이 우상단 좌표
            bottomLeft = biggest_fake[np.argmax(diff)]  # x-y가 가장 큰 값이 좌하단 좌표

            # 변환 전 4개 좌표
            pts1 = np.float32([topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft])

            # 변환 후 영상에 사용할 서류의 폭과 높이 계산
            w1 = abs(bottomRight[0] - bottomLeft[0])
            w2 = abs(topRight[0] - topLeft[0])
            h1 = abs(topRight[1] - bottomRight[1])
            h2 = abs(topLeft[1] - bottomLeft[1])
            width = max([w1, w2])  # 두 좌우 거리간의 최대값이 서류의 폭
            height = max([h1, h2])  # 두 상하 거리간의 최대값이 서류의 높이

            # 변환 후 4개 좌표
            pts2 = np.float32([[0, 0], [width - 1, 0],
                               [width - 1, height - 1], [0, height - 1]])

            # 변환 행렬 계산
            mtrx = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2)
            # 원근 변환 적용
            warpFrame = cv2.warpPerspective(img, mtrx, (width, height))

if len(biggest) != 0 :
    CornerFrame = cv2.drawContours(CornerFrame, biggest, -1, (255, 0, 255), 25)

GrayImg_1 = cv2.cvtColor(warpFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
dilated_img =cv2.dilate(GrayImg_1,np.ones((7,7),np.uint8))
bg_img=cv2.medianBlur(dilated_img,21)
diff_img = 255 - cv2.absdiff(GrayImg_1, bg_img)
norm_img = diff_img.copy() # Needed for 3.x compatibility
cv2.normalize(diff_img, norm_img, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8UC1)
_, thr_img = cv2.threshold(norm_img, 230, 0, cv2.THRESH_TRUNC)
cv2.normalize(thr_img, thr_img, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8UC1)

cv2.imwrite('save_image.jpg',thr_img,[cv2.IMWRITE_TIFF_RESUNIT,600])

# resizing
img = cv2.resize(img, (480, 640))

#remove_shadow_img = cv2.resize(remove_shadow_img, (480, 640))
#remove_shadow_img_norm = cv2.resize(remove_shadow_img_norm, (480, 640))
GaussianImg = cv2.resize(GaussianImg, (480, 640))
CannyFrame = cv2.resize(CannyFrame, (480, 640))
#bilateralImg = cv2.resize(bilateralImg, (480, 640))
CornerFrame = cv2.resize(CornerFrame, (480, 640))
#edgeImg = cv2.resize(edgeImg, (480, 640))
resultFrame = cv2.resize(thr_img, (480, 640))



#displaying
cv2.imshow("img", img)
#cv2.imshow("remove_shadow_img_norm", remove_shadow_img_norm)
#cv2.imshow("remove_shadow_img", remove_shadow_img)
cv2.imshow("CannyFrame", CannyFrame)
cv2.imshow("GaussianImg", GaussianImg)
#cv2.imshow("bilateralImg", bilateralImg)
cv2.imshow("CornerFrame", CornerFrame)
#cv2.imshow("edgeImg", edgeImg)
cv2.imshow("resultFrame", thr_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Do you think you can set some constraints for photographing such as putting the book on a plain background?

Comment: we can set the book background. Then, how should I recognize books?